# Unable to run Crossrider extension on firefox, not even in debug mode

Tags: crossrider

I am unable to run my Crossrider extension on Firefox 34.0.5.

I have enabled all about:config needed variables in order to trace errors but can't get any error in the consoles (page console, browser console).

I am also unable to install the extension in debug mode, getting a message of
"Failure installing the debug extension of your Crossrider Extension"
each and everytime, without any errors in the consoles.

May that be a bug in Crossrider's system?

I am however able to run the extension in Chrome and Safari, IE does not run it as well, but that is another story.

I'm clueless, did anyone experienced these problem?

Comment: Usually extensions built using Crossrdider run on Firefox 34 without any issue; hence, to answer your question I need to take a look at your extension. Therefore, if you can provide and extension id and the OS version you are using, I'd be happy to take a look. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Hey Shlomo, thanks for replying.

My extension ID is 66801 and I couldn't even install it in debug mode, before even applying the base URL for my extension files to load, meaning the problem is probably not in my code. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I can reproduce the problem but at this time it's not clear to me why it's happening. However, I tried cloning the extension and it works fine. Are you able to workaround the issue by cloning the extension?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply
I tried cloning the extension, but got the exact same message saying: 'Failure installing the debug extension of your Crossrider Extension'. This is frustrating :(
And I didn't even get to IE yet hehe
Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I just created a new extension from scratch, without cloning the original one, and managed to install it in debug mode. Hopefully, I'll get things running from now on, thank you very much.

Comment: Well.. I installed your basic "alert("My new Crossrider extension works!..." extension on Firefox, and it won't alert even after being installed properly...
I guess there are some major issues with Firefox at your side.. Let me know if there's anything I might be doing wrong